# SSIS - Package variable not getting initialised

Tags: ssis

I have a Execute SQL task. This task gets a recordcount after querying a table.

The query that I am using is

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 
  (SELECT COUNT(FUND_STATUS) AS [Fund Status]
                              FROM dbo.FundPrice
                              WHERE fund_status != 'EXPIRED')
```

When I try to open the build query it says does not support Declare statement, however the the task executes sucessfully. I have created a package variable called `RowCount`.

I have set the mapping in the execute script task such that variable name is `User:RowCount` and Direction is Output and DataType is LONG and Parameter  = @RowCount

I have then created a script task. In the script task I am reading the package variable

```
 var rowCount = Dts.Variables["RowCount"].Value;
```

However when I run the package in debug mode, the value of rowcount is 0 though there are 1000 rows in the table that match the query. Could someone tell me 
what the problem is ?

Comment: Try to use the `Execute T-SQL Statement Task Component`

Comment: i am using sql2008 r2. I dont see a tsql task

Comment: in your `Toolbox` go to `Maintenance plan tasks` you will see `Execute T-SQL Statement Task`

Comment: Could you let me know why I need to TSQL as that I dont get an error in Execute SQL task. All that I am not getting is value in the script task.

Comment: you want the `count` of your `rows` and save the number of your `count` in `a variable` ?

Comment: I just tried using tsql task. The box flags red but cant see the error message. I have set the maxerrorcount property to 1000. Yet cant see what the error is

Comment: I see this error message [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "DECLARE @RowCount INT =  (SELECT COUNT(FUND_STATUS..." failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near 'Fund Status'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: My question is what's the result that you want ? because i see in your example you save `the number of rows` in a `variable` if this is your question you can do it differently

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103725/discussion-between-tom-and-download-dowload).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a picture of you work will be

[image]
Firstly : add new **DataFlow** in side your data flow add your `source table` and add the Compenent `Row Count` see the picture as bellow

[image]

Secondly : double Click in `Row Count Component` and in `the component properties tab` go to `variable name` and add your `variable` see the picture as bellow
[image]

Thirdly : in `Script Component` double click and select your `variable` see the picture as bellow

[image]

Finally : Click in the `Edit Script` and inside `main Method write this code`

```
MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::RowCount"].Value.ToString());
```

For more information see the picture as bellow :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly